# How can I make a string with expandable keywords in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm writing a GIMP script to export layers to files. I want to provide a user-specifiable field where they can provide the format for the filenames to be exported, with tilde-character combinations for each element (ie. a file named "foo" with layers "bar" and "baz", with the output filename format being "~f-~l.png", would output "foo-bar.png" and "foo-baz.png"). I know how I would do this in Lua:

```lua
local nameformat = "~f-~l.png"
local function layer_export_name(filename, layername)
  return string.gsub(nameformat, '~.', {f=filename, l=layername})
end
```

How can I do this in GIMP's Scheme?

To reiterate: I need to replace **keywords in a string**. I don't need a function that creates a string I've already defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard Scheme procedure to do this. I wrote the following in-efficient but portable procedure:

```
(define (expand-keywords string tokens)
  (let loop ((slist (string->list string))
             (in-replace-mode #f)
             (result ""))
    (if (not (null? slist))        
        (let ((c (car slist)))
          (cond (in-replace-mode
                 (let ((token (car (cdr (assoc c tokens)))))
                   (loop (cdr slist) #f (string-append result token))))
                ((char=? c #\~)
                 (loop (cdr slist) #t result))
                (else 
                 (loop (cdr slist) #f (string-append result 
                                                     (make-string 1 c))))))
        result)))
```

Sample usage:

```
> (expand-keywords "~f-~l.png" '((#\f "vijay") (#\l "9")))
"vijay-9.png"
> (expand-keywords "~f-~l.~e" '((#\f "vijay") (#\l "10") (#\e "jpg")))
"vijay-10.jpg"
```

If your Scheme implementation provides a procedure to modify a string in-place, use that instead of `string-append`.

Comment: It's not pretty, but it does what it's supposed to, with the resources available.

Comment: How can I nest this function definition within the scope of another function?

Comment: @Stuart P. Bentley In Scheme you can do this: `(define (func) (define (nested-func) (...)) ...)`

Comment: @Stuart P. Bentley Try this: `(define (func) (let ((nested-func (lambda () ..))) ..))`

Answer (score 0):

BIG CAVEAT: I know lots of Scheme, but not lots of GIMP scheme--apparently TinyScheme. In Racket, for instance, you would write

```
(format "~a-~a.png" filename layername)
```

... assuming that layername is a string (it's not clear to me from your question whether this is the case).

I'm guessing that you don't have racket's "format" in TinyScheme, but you almost certainly have "string-append":

```
(string-append filename "-" layername ".png")
```

If layername is a string, you'll probably also want to use the number->string function, like this:

```
(string-append filename "-" (number->string layername) ".png")
```

Comment: That doesn't allow users to specify where to use the filename and where to use the layername.

Comment: Per your clarification above, I see that I *completely* misunderstood your question. The language semanticist in me suggests that the string is not really a very robust specification, but I see that it's a convenient one. Vijay's answer looks good!